# To have the initial as well as updated value of static variable

Tags: java

Sample input and output

Enter no of bookings:
2

Enter the available tickets:
25

Enter the ticketid:
123

Enter the price:
100

Enter the no of tickets:
5

Available tickets: 25

Total amount:500

Available ticket after booking:20

Enter the ticketid:
124

Enter the price:
100

Enter the no of tickets:
2

Available tickets: 20

Total amount:200

Available ticket after booking:18

My code is:
Ticket.java

```
    1     public class Ticket {
    2     private int ticketid;
    3     private int price;
    4     int amount;
    5     private static int availableTickets;
    6     
    7     public void setTicketid(int ticketid){
    8         this. ticketid=ticketid ;
    9     }
   10     public void setPrice(int price ){
   11         this.price = price;
   12     }
   13     
   14     public void setAvailableTickets(int availableTickets ){
   15         if(availableTickets>0)
   16         this.availableTickets = availableTickets ;
   17     }
   18     public int calculateTicketCost(int noofticket)
   19     {
   20         if(availableTickets>noofticket)
   21         {
   22             availableTickets = availableTickets - noofticket;
   23             setAvailableTickets(availableTickets);
   24             amount = noofticket*price;
   25             return amount;
   26         }
   27         else
   28         return -1;
   29     }
   30     public int getAvailableTickets(){
   31         return this.availableTickets;
   32     }
   33     public int getTicketid(){
   34         return this.ticketid;
   35     }
   36     public int getPrice(){
   37         return this.price;
   38     }
   39     
   40 }
```

Main.java

```
    1 import java.util.Scanner;
    2 public class Main {
    3     public static void main (String[] args) {
    4         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    5         Ticket t = new Ticket();
    6         System.out.println("Enter the no of bookings:");
    7         int b = sc.nextInt();
    8         System.out.println("Enter the available tickets:");
    9         t.setAvailableTickets(sc.nextInt());
   10         while(b>0){
   11         System.out.println("Enter the ticketid:");
   12         t.setTicketid(sc.nextInt());
   13         System.out.println("Enter the price:");
   14         t.setPrice(sc.nextInt());
   15         System.out.println("Enter the no of tickets:");
   16         int n = sc.nextInt();
   17         int cost = t.calculateTicketCost(n);
   18         System.out.println("Available Tickets: "+t.getAvailableTickets());
   19         System.out.println("Total amount:"+cost);
   20         System.out.println("Available ticket after booking:"+t.getAvailableTickets());
   21         }
   22     }
   23 }
```

My output for my code is:

Enter the no of bookings:
2
Enter the available tickets:
25
Enter the ticketid:
123
Enter the price:
100
Enter the no of tickets:
5
Available Tickets: 20
Total amount:500
Available ticket after booking:20
Enter the ticketid:
124
Enter the price:
100
Enter the no of tickets:
2
Available Tickets: 18
Total amount:200
Available ticket after booking:18

So the Available tickets are not coming correct. It should first come initial value then updated value but it is coming only updated value.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Ticket t = new Ticket();
        System.out.println("Enter the no of bookings:");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the available tickets:");
        t.setAvailableTickets(sc.nextInt());
        while (b > 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the ticketid:");
            t.setTicketid(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Enter the price:");
            t.setPrice(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Enter the no of tickets:");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Available Tickets: " + t.getAvailableTickets());
            int cost = t.calculateTicketCost(n);
            System.out.println("Total amount:" + cost);
            System.out.println("Available ticket after booking:" + t.getAvailableTickets());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have placed `System.out.println("Available Tickets: " + t.getAvailableTickets());` before `int cost = t.calculateTicketCost(n);`.

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the no of bookings:
2
Enter the available tickets:
25
Enter the ticketid:
123
Enter the price:
100
Enter the no of tickets:
5
Available Tickets: 25
Total amount:500
Available ticket after booking:20
Enter the ticketid:
124
Enter the price:
100
Enter the no of tickets:
2
Available Tickets: 20
Total amount:200
Available ticket after booking:18
Enter the ticketid:
```

**Note:** You have unnecessarily declared `availableTickets` as `static`. Remove the `static` keyword from it.

Comment: Thanks this provide the solution to my problem.

Comment: There is one more thing it still shows the following test case failed, can you please help:  Incorrect access specifier/modifier for the method setAvailableTickets in the class Ticket  -Should be a [public, static]
Incorrect access specifier/modifier for the method getAvailableTickets in the class Ticket  -Should be a [public, static]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new variable that holds the initial amount of tickets on your `Ticket` class.

```
private int initialTickets;

public void setAvailableTickets(int availableTickets ){
    if(availableTickets>0) {
        this.availableTickets = availableTickets;
        initialTickets = availableTickets;
    }
public int getInitialTickets() {
    return initialTickets;
}
```

And then on your main

```
System.out.println("Available Tickets: " + t.getInitialAmountTickets());
```